# Using Qt Data Visualization to plot 3D points on 3D surfaces

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt5, qtdatavisualization

While Qt Data Visualization can plots 3D scatter plots and 3D surfaces, it seems it can only do it separately. Is there any way I can overlay these two graphs? i.e., plot some 3D points on a 3D surface.